Ag Grid showing garbage icon in production
I am using ag-grid-table in my project.
somehow it is showing correct icons in the local environment but not in the production environment
here is the production environment screenshot
here is local environment screenshot

   "ag-grid-community": "^31.3.2",
   "ag-grid-enterprise": "^31.3.2",
   "ag-grid-react": "^31.3.2",
   "react": "18.2.0",
   "react-dom": "^18.2.0",



anyone can help here

Does this answer your question? icons are not displaying properly - ag grid

How to replace ag grid checkbox check mark font icon by another one?
implemented this. Working fine in production. But original ag grid icons does not show properly is still an issue
